# Troubleshooting high CPU usage from postgres and postmaster services?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using an open source (RHEL 6.2) based machine running SIEM software. When I run the `top` command, I see `postgres` and `postmaster` both with 96% CPU usage. Is there a way to pin-point or see what causing these service to stack up?

Comment: "RHCE 6.2"? Do you mean "RHEL 6.2" ? I assume `postgress` is `postgres` and you've just copied it by hand.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can match a specific Postgres backend ID to a system process ID using the `pg_stat_activity` system table.

`SELECT pid, datname, usename, query FROM pg_stat_activity;` can be a good starting point.
Once you know what queries are running you can investigate further (`EXPLAIN`/`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`; check locks, etc.)

Comment: is this the exact query, I'm not much familiar with db as im the sec guy working on siem, your select statement, do i have to feed it pid from top command ?

Comment: @asadz no, it was truncated (fixed now) -- If you have specific PIDs and want to see what they're running you can isolate them with a `WHERE` clause, but if you don't have a huge number of PIDs it's just as easy to search through the full output. [The Postgres manual has additional detail on what you can get out of `pg_stat_activity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW), as well as the other statistics-collector tables (which can help you if your problem *isn't* a user query).

Comment: when I execute this query, there is no PID that I have to suspect

Comment: Thanks for the clue, recently I met similar issue and figured out the reason by using **SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;**

Answer (score 32):

I was having the same issue. The postgresql is setup on AWS RDS and it was having 100% cpu utilisation even after increasing the instance. I debugged with the method shown [**here**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/10/debug-postgresql-performance-issues.html) and one of the method worked for me.

I checked for the query running for the longest time and came to know that certain queries was stuck and was running since more than 3-4 hours. To check since how much time the query is running, run the following command:

```
SELECT max(now() - xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity
                               WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');
```

If this is more than an hour, than this is the issue. Kill the long running connection and limit the max age of the connection from application side.

Answer (score 12):

If this is really the postmaster using all that CPU, then you likely have lock contention issues, probably due to very high `max_connections`. Consider lowering `max_connections` and using a connection pooler if this is the case.

Otherwise: Details, please. Full output of `top -b -n 1` for a start.

Comment: this make sense ; since the siem is used by analyst to query lot of data back and forth; is there a way i can check on the lock status; or conditions attributed to it; ?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `pg_stat_statements`,
      https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html.

First, `pg_stat_activity` (from the other answers) is good advice — and I think sometimes it's not enough? It shows the *current* activity only, but what if there are many many quick queries, which don't last long enough for them to look interesting in `pg_stat_activity`? However when there're many many of them, they might still cause high CPU usage?

Then you can use `pg_stat_statements`:

> pg_stat_statements records queries that are run against your database, strips out a number of variables from them, and then saves data about the query, such as how long it took, as well as what happened to underlying reads/writes.

(From this blog post: [The most useful Postgres extension: pg_stat_statements](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2019/02/08/the-most-useful-postgres-extension-pg-stat-statements/) )

Here I use it to find out why my own CPU usage is unexpectedly high:

```
\x

select 
  (total_exec_time / 1000 / 3600) as total_hours,
  (total_exec_time / 1000) as total_seconds,
  (total_exec_time / calls) as avg_millis, 
  calls num_calls,
  query 
from pg_stat_statements 
order by 1 desc limit 10;


-[ RECORD 1 ]-+-------------------------
total_hours   | 0.128210291016666
total_seconds | 461.557047659998
avg_millis    | 9.06506889111474
num_calls     | 50916
query         | select p.site_id, p.page_id, p.version current_version, h.page_version cached_version from  ...
-[ RECORD 2 ]-+------------------------
total_hours   | 0.0586912504452778
total_seconds | 211.288501603
avg_millis    | 4.14966517279101
num_calls     | 50917
query         | select p.site_id, p.page_id ... from ...
:
:
```

Did you notice something, above?  — There top queries are quick: 0.009 and 0.004 seconds. But they get called many many times.

(You could also try `total_plan_time + total_exec_time` instead of just `total_exec_time`.)

Comment: Looks like that since PostgreSQL 13, the `total_time` column doesn't exist anymore, it was changed to `total_exec_time`

Answer (score 4):

I would like to recommend the [`pg_activity` utility](https://github.com/dalibo/pg_activity) to see which SQL queries use CPU\RAM. Very useful, like `top`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar in Postgres 9.1 and I've solved it by increasing `shared_buffers` and `effective_cache_size` parameters.

The official [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-resource.html) says:

> **shared_buffers (integer)**
>
> Sets the amount of memory the database server uses for shared memory
> buffers. The default is typically 32 megabytes (32MB), but might be
> less if your kernel settings will not support it (as determined during
> initdb). This setting must be at least 128 kilobytes. (Non-default
> values of BLCKSZ change the minimum.) However, settings significantly
> higher than the minimum are usually needed for good performance. This
> parameter can only be set at server start.
>
> If you have a dedicated database server with 1GB or more of RAM, a
> reasonable starting value for shared_buffers is 25% of the memory in
> your system. There are some workloads where even large settings for
> shared_buffers are effective, but because PostgreSQL also relies on
> the operating system cache, it is unlikely that an allocation of more
> than 40% of RAM to shared_buffers will work better than a smaller
> amount. Larger settings for shared_buffers usually require a
> corresponding increase in checkpoint_segments, in order to spread out
> the process of writing large quantities of new or changed data over a
> longer period of time.
>
> On systems with less than 1GB of RAM, a smaller percentage of RAM is
> appropriate, so as to leave adequate space for the operating system.
> Also, on Windows, large values for shared_buffers aren't as effective.
> You may find better results keeping the setting relatively low and
> using the operating system cache more instead. The useful range for
> shared_buffers on Windows systems is generally from 64MB to 512MB.
>
> Increasing this parameter might cause PostgreSQL to request more
> System V shared memory than your operating system's default
> configuration allows. See Section 17.4.1 for information on how to
> adjust those parameters, if necessary.

In a system with 64GB of RAM and totally dedicated to Postgres only, I've set:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_buffers = '8GB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET effective_cache_size = '32GB';
```

But depending of you Postgres' version and your Linux distribution, it will not be possible to initialize your database with those values in each parameter, due to Linux `kernel.shmmax` limitations.

You can change it by running:

```
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=14294967296
```

where `14294967296` is the size (in bytes) you'd limit.

> [SHMMAX](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/29/tune-linux-kernel-parameters-for-postgresql-optimization/#:%7E:text=SHMMAX%20is%20a%20kernel%20parameter,of%20System%20V%20shared%20memory.) is a kernel parameter used to define the maximum size of a
> single shared memory segment a Linux process can allocate.