# Monitor most popular queries?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

We're trying to track down a performance issue in our PostgreSQL database.

We suspect of some under-performing queries, but which?

Is it possible to find the most popular queries being executed on the database?

What about their performance, how long they're taking?

It's PostgreSQL 11, hosted in Google Cloud's CloudSQL.

Comment: Quick first thing to check is [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW); if you have a particular query that's reliably show and this is a DB with a reasonably high QPS, you should see a bunch of backends in the active state handling the same (or similar) queries.

Comment: You are looking for `pg_stat_statements`, see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103597/how-to-check-know-the-highest-run-queries/132299#132299), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92071/get-statistics-of-slow-running-queries/230678#230678), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44084/troubleshooting-high-cpu-usage-from-postgres-and-postmaster-services/259819#259819) or many other questions.